# Identify new elements in a list [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hash

I have an ever-updating list with duplicate elements, like

```py
# 10 elements
some_list = ['hello', 'hi', 'bye', 'hello', 'okay']
```

So I was using the list index and the list element together and hashing them, to create unique hashes and storing them on redis.

Since, this runs in while True, I need to constantly check for new elements towards the end of the list, it works when the list keeps updating and growing,
but under a specific condition, the list resets such that a new element is added to it at the end and starting element is removed (it's a valid case).

The new list looks like, this:

```py
# 10 elements
some_list = ['hi', 'bye', 'hello', 'okay', 'new_element']
```

In such a case, since the index of every element changed, the hashes are different and it puts every element in redis.

Any solution that can help me identify how to identify old elements all the while adding new ones, would be highly appreciated.

Please post comments if the information provided seems ambigous or insufficent.

Comment: can you add what you tried so far

Comment: I'm not sure I can share the code, as it's work related, but  hash('hi' + index of 'hi'), is being used to calculate the hashes and this is stored in redis

Comment: Can you make a second list, otherwise identical to the first list except it doesn't "reset" in this case, and compare it to the first list to find duplicate elements?

Answer (score 0):

If possible in your case you could solve the problem by using an ordered dictionary instead. You can then use the keys as bookkeeping parameters to check for new elements..

Comment: It's possible for me to change my architecture as of this moment, but I don't understand how I would exactly use an ordered dict to manage new elements, also the elements can repeat themselves (If using an element as key was part of your answer)

Comment: @piyushdaga It depends on how exactly you add elements and check for elements but I would probably index every new element with an integer as key and what ever you want to store as the value. This way every 'what ever' is assigned to a fix index. They indices you could store in a list and from that (maybe by the lists length...?) find out if a new element was added to your dict.

Answer (score 0):

while I think the other answer is the most elegant and correct, this is a workaround in case changing the architecture of your software wasn't a viable option.

Maybe you could use a list of timestamps to keep track of when entries are added.
So, to every entry in your "redis" list, there would be a corresponding entry in your "timestamp" list. The timestamp (or its hash) can be used as identification on Redis as well. All you have to make sure of is that for each entry in the "redis" list, a corresponding timestamp is added on the "timestamp" list. Same when you delete the first element.

Comment: I actually thought of this solution but, those elements in the reset list, come as new elements completely, so I'm not completely sold on the timestamp's implementation

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the following class to accomplish what you are after:

```
from typing import List, Iterator, Iterable, Union, overload, Optional, \
    Callable, Any


class UniqueError(ValueError):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('all values in a UniqueList must be distinct')
        raise self


class UniqueList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable=()) -> None:
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.__unique = set(self)
        if len(self) != len(self.__unique):
            UniqueError()

    def clear(self) -> None:
        super().clear()
        self.__unique.clear()

    def copy(self) -> List[Any]:
        type_self = type(self)
        instance = type_self.__new__(type_self)
        super(type_self, instance).__init__(self)
        instance.__unique = self.__unique.copy()
        return instance

    def append(self, obj: Any) -> None:
        if obj in self.__unique:
            UniqueError()
        self.__unique.add(obj)
        super().append(obj)

    def extend(self, iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> None:
        copy = list(iterable)
        if any(obj in self.__unique for obj in copy):
            UniqueError()
        super().extend(copy)

    def pop(self, index: int = ...) -> Any:
        value = super().pop(index)
        self.__unique.remove(value)
        return value

    def index(self, obj: Any, start: int = ..., stop: int = ...) -> int:
        return super().index(obj, start, stop)

    def count(self, obj: Any) -> int:
        return int(obj in self.__unique)

    def insert(self, index: int, obj: Any) -> None:
        if obj in self.__unique:
            UniqueError()
        self.__unique.add(obj)
        super().insert(index, obj)

    def remove(self, obj: Any) -> None:
        super().remove(obj)
        self.__unique.remove(obj)

    def reverse(self) -> None:
        super().reverse()

    def sort(self, *, key: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]] = ...,
             reverse: bool = ...) -> None:
        super().sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return super().__len__()

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Any]:
        return super().__iter__()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return super().__str__()

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return super().__hash__()

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> Any: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> List[Any]: ...

    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> Any:
        return super().__getitem__(i)

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, i: int, o: Any) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, s: slice, o: Iterable[Any]) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(self, i: int, o: Any) -> None:
        current = super().__getitem__(i)
        if current == o or o in self.__unique:
            UniqueError()
        self.__unique.add(o)
        self.__unique.remove(current)
        super().__setitem__(i, o)

    def __delitem__(self, i: Union[int, slice]) -> None:
        self.__unique.remove(super().__getitem__(i))
        super().__delitem__(i)

    def __add__(self, x: List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
        copy = self.copy()
        copy += x
        return copy

    def __iadd__(self, x: Iterable[Any]) -> List[Any]:
        self.extend(x)
        return self

    def __mul__(self, n: int) -> List[Any]:
        raise NotImplementedError('multiplication is not supported')

    def __rmul__(self, n: int) -> List[Any]:
        raise NotImplementedError('multiplication is not supported')

    def __imul__(self, n: int) -> List[Any]:
        raise NotImplementedError('multiplication is not supported')

    def __contains__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        return super().__contains__(o)

    def __reversed__(self) -> Iterator[Any]:
        return super().__reversed__()

    def __gt__(self, x: List[Any]) -> bool:
        return super().__gt__(x)

    def __ge__(self, x: List[Any]) -> bool:
        return super().__ge__(x)

    def __lt__(self, x: List[Any]) -> bool:
        return super().__lt__(x)

    def __le__(self, x: List[Any]) -> bool:
        return super().__le__(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `list` does not seem to be an appropriate datatype. Firstly, very large lists will become unfeasible when comparing all elements with another, i.e. the performance characteristics of your sort-of queue are quadratic. This may not be an issue for you, neither does this answer your question.

You may also want to look at [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), which does not answer your question either, but may still be helpful.

Also, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) may be of interest.

From your question it is not clear, whether you need to remember all ever visited strings, or only those of the current list. For remembering seen strings consider using a `set`, as already suggested.

My final suggestion is: Instead of removing/dropping the head elements you may want to set them to `None` or `PLACEHOLDER = object()`, in order to preserve indices.

Good Luck.